# Почему float умножение быстрее чем целочисленное?

Tags: c++

В одном блоге встретил такой вопрос при найме на работу. Хорошо знаком с аппаратными алгоритмами умножения, но все равно ответить не могу на вопрос:-)

UPD. У нас есть современный процессор, в котором сопроцессоров уже нету. Есть ядро в котором много различных блоков для обработки данных FPU, SSE, MMX и прочих. Возможно разрешение вопроса лежит в области GPU вычислений.

Comment: а что вообще нужно показать? как оно в принципе может быть быстрее, или подробно описать, как и почему такое происходит?

Comment: Как оно впринципе может быть быстрее? засчет плохой реализации только :-D

Comment: Где вы такое нашли? ) Я где-то встречал, что целочисленное деление медленнее float-деления, про умножение первый раз слышу...

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос основан на неверном предположении.

Answer (score 4):

Экспериментально никак не получается получить целочисленное умножение более медленным, чем float. Возможно, если для целочисленных операций сделать long long int и запускать на 32-битном процессоре, то тогда будет медленнее. У меня на 64битном умножение float-ов и long-long-int'ов почти сравнялось во времени (+-1 секунда)

Кстати, интересное наблюдение: собрал с ключём -m32 и при выполнении на 64битном камне скорость упала до катастрофически-низкой, но даже тогда float-умножение выполняется медленнее. И никакие ключи типа fast-math и т.п. не помогают. Видимо речь о каком-то очень частном случае в каких-то очень неравных условиях.

Вот мой тест, если кому интересно:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    const long long int count = 100000000;
    time_t start, end;

    time(0);
    {
    long long int a = 7;

    time(&start);
    for(long long int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
    }
    time(&end);

    printf("a = %lld, time = %d\n", a, (int)(end - start));
    }
    {
    float a = 7e200;
    time(&start);
    for(long long int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
        a = a * 999;
    }
    time(&end);

    printf("a = %f, time = %d\n", a, (int)(end - start));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

А вот его результаты с разными вариациями:

```
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ g++ -ffast-math -m32 main.cc
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ ./a.out                     
a = 7409966934681833479, time = 6
a = inf, time = 146
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ g++ -ffast-math main.cc     
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ ./a.out                
a = 7409966934681833479, time = 5
a = inf, time = 6
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ g++  main.cc           
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ ./a.out     
a = 7409966934681833479, time = 4
a = inf, time = 6
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ g++ -m32  main.cc
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ ./a.out          
a = 7409966934681833479, time = 6
a = inf, time = 145
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ 
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep name 
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ uname -a
Linux cgmachine 2.6.33.7-desktop-2mnb #1 SMP Mon Sep 20 18:19:20 UTC 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $
```

Как видно, все результаты одного порядка. Кроме случая выполнения умножения float'а в режиме эмуляции (выполнение 32битного кода в 64битном окружении). Однако, float умножение всегда немного отстаёт. Если count увеличить в десять раз, то разница ещё более заметна

```
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ g++  main.cc                 
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $ ./a.out                      
a = 3874608091370758151, time = 42
a = inf, time = 57
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine tests/cpp/2 $
```

Если же общая нагрузка на систему выше (много разных процессов выполняют операции с плавающей запятой), то разница будет ещё более заметной, так как переключение контекстов, выполняющих операции с плавающей запятой обходятся дорого.

**UPD**: по просьбе трудящихся привожу дамп для простой сборки без всех ключей:

```
00000000004005c4 <main>:
4005c4: 55                      push   %rbp
4005c5: 48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
4005c8: 48 83 ec 40             sub    $0x40,%rsp
4005cc: 48 c7 45 d8 00 ca 9a    movq   $0x3b9aca00,-0x28(%rbp)
4005d3: 3b 
4005d4: bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
4005d9: e8 f2 fe ff ff          callq  4004d0 <time@plt>
4005de: 48 c7 45 e0 07 00 00    movq   $0x7,-0x20(%rbp)
4005e5: 00 
4005e6: 48 8d 45 d0             lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
4005ea: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
4005ed: e8 de fe ff ff          callq  4004d0 <time@plt>
4005f2: 48 c7 45 e8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
4005f9: 00 
4005fa: e9 9b 00 00 00          jmpq   40069a <main+0xd6>
4005ff: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
400603: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
40060a: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
40060e: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
400612: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400619: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
40061d: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
400621: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400628: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
40062c: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
400630: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400637: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
40063b: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40063f: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400646: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
40064a: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40064e: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400655: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
400659: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40065d: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400664: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
400668: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40066c: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400673: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
400677: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40067b: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400682: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
400686: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40068a: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400691: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
400695: 48 83 45 e8 01          addq   $0x1,-0x18(%rbp)
40069a: 48 81 7d e8 ff c9 9a    cmpq   $0x3b9ac9ff,-0x18(%rbp)
4006a1: 3b 
4006a2: 0f 9e c0                setle  %al
4006a5: 84 c0                   test   %al,%al
4006a7: 0f 85 52 ff ff ff       jne    4005ff <main+0x3b>
4006ad: 48 8d 45 c8             lea    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
4006b1: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
4006b4: e8 17 fe ff ff          callq  4004d0 <time@plt>
4006b9: 48 8b 45 c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
4006bd: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
4006bf: 48 8b 45 d0             mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
4006c3: 89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
4006c5: 29 c1                   sub    %eax,%ecx
4006c7: 89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
4006c9: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
4006cb: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
4006cf: 48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
4006d2: bf 2c 09 40 00          mov    $0x40092c,%edi
4006d7: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
4006dc: e8 bf fd ff ff          callq  4004a0 <printf@plt>
4006e1: b8 00 00 80 7f          mov    $0x7f800000,%eax
4006e6: 89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)
4006e9: 48 8d 45 d0             lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
4006ed: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
4006f0: e8 db fd ff ff          callq  4004d0 <time@plt>
4006f5: 48 c7 45 f8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
4006fc: 00 
4006fd: e9 e1 00 00 00          jmpq   4007e3 <main+0x21f>
400702: f3 0f 10 4d f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm1
400707: f3 0f 10 05 45 02 00    movss  0x245(%rip),%xmm0        # 400954 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
40070e: 00 
40070f: f3 0f 59 c1             mulss  %xmm1,%xmm0
400713: f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
400718: f3 0f 10 4d f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm1
40071d: f3 0f 10 05 2f 02 00    movss  0x22f(%rip),%xmm0        # 400954 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
400724: 00 
400725: f3 0f 59 c1             mulss  %xmm1,%xmm0
400729: f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
40072e: f3 0f 10 4d f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm1
400733: f3 0f 10 05 19 02 00    movss  0x219(%rip),%xmm0        # 400954 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
40073a: 00 
40073b: f3 0f 59 c1             mulss  %xmm1,%xmm0
40073f: f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
400744: f3 0f 10 4d f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm1
400749: f3 0f 10 05 03 02 00    movss  0x203(%rip),%xmm0        # 400954 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
400750: 00 
400751: f3 0f 59 c1             mulss  %xmm1,%xmm0
400755: f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
40075a: f3 0f 10 4d f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm1
40075f: f3 0f 10 05 ed 01 00    movss  0x1ed(%rip),%xmm0        # 400954 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
400766: 00 
400767: f3 0f 59 c1             mulss  %xmm1,%xmm0
40076b: f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
400770: f3 0f 10 4d f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm1
400775: f3 0f 10 05 d7 01 00    movss  0x1d7(%rip),%xmm0        # 400954 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
40077c: 00 
40077d: f3 0f 59 c1             mulss  %xmm1,%xmm0
400781: f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
400786: f3 0f 10 4d f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm1
40078b: f3 0f 10 05 c1 01 00    movss  0x1c1(%rip),%xmm0        # 400954 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
400792: 00 
400793: f3 0f 59 c1             mulss  %xmm1,%xmm0
400797: f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
40079c: f3 0f 10 4d f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm1
4007a1: f3 0f 10 05 ab 01 00    movss  0x1ab(%rip),%xmm0        # 400954 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
4007a8: 00 
4007a9: f3 0f 59 c1             mulss  %xmm1,%xmm0
4007ad: f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
4007b2: f3 0f 10 4d f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm1
4007b7: f3 0f 10 05 95 01 00    movss  0x195(%rip),%xmm0        # 400954 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
4007be: 00 
4007bf: f3 0f 59 c1             mulss  %xmm1,%xmm0
4007c3: f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
4007c8: f3 0f 10 4d f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm1
4007cd: f3 0f 10 05 7f 01 00    movss  0x17f(%rip),%xmm0        # 400954 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
4007d4: 00 
4007d5: f3 0f 59 c1             mulss  %xmm1,%xmm0
4007d9: f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
4007de: 48 83 45 f8 01          addq   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
4007e3: 48 81 7d f8 ff c9 9a    cmpq   $0x3b9ac9ff,-0x8(%rbp)
4007ea: 3b 
4007eb: 0f 9e c0                setle  %al
4007ee: 84 c0                   test   %al,%al
4007f0: 0f 85 0c ff ff ff       jne    400702 <main+0x13e>
4007f6: 48 8d 45 c8             lea    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
4007fa: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
4007fd: e8 ce fc ff ff          callq  4004d0 <time@plt>
400802: 48 8b 45 c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
400806: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
400808: 48 8b 45 d0             mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
40080c: 89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
40080e: 29 c1                   sub    %eax,%ecx
400810: 89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
400812: f3 0f 10 45 f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm0
400817: 0f 5a c0                cvtps2pd %xmm0,%xmm0
40081a: 89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
40081c: bf 41 09 40 00          mov    $0x400941,%edi
400821: b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
400826: e8 75 fc ff ff          callq  4004a0 <printf@plt>
40082b: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
400830: c9                      leaveq 
400831: c3                      retq   
400832: 90                      nop
400833: 90                      nop
400834: 90                      nop
400835: 90                      nop
400836: 90                      nop
400837: 90                      nop
400838: 90                      nop
400839: 90                      nop
40083a: 90                      nop
40083b: 90                      nop
40083c: 90                      nop
40083d: 90                      nop
40083e: 90                      nop
40083f: 90                      nop
```

А вот если собрать с ключами -march=core2 -mfpmath=both  то удет сгенерирован несколько другой код:

```
00000000004005c4 <main>:
4005c4: 55                      push   %rbp
4005c5: 48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
4005c8: 48 83 ec 40             sub    $0x40,%rsp
4005cc: 48 c7 45 d8 00 ca 9a    movq   $0x3b9aca00,-0x28(%rbp)
4005d3: 3b 
4005d4: bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
4005d9: e8 f2 fe ff ff          callq  4004d0 <time@plt>
4005de: 48 c7 45 e0 07 00 00    movq   $0x7,-0x20(%rbp)
4005e5: 00 
4005e6: 48 8d 45 d0             lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
4005ea: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
4005ed: e8 de fe ff ff          callq  4004d0 <time@plt>
4005f2: 48 c7 45 e8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
4005f9: 00 
4005fa: e9 9a 00 00 00          jmpq   400699 <main+0xd5>
4005ff: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
400603: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
40060a: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
40060e: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
400612: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400619: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
40061d: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
400621: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400628: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
40062c: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
400630: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400637: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
40063b: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40063f: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400646: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
40064a: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40064e: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400655: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
400659: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40065d: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400664: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
400668: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40066c: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400673: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
400677: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40067b: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400682: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
400686: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
40068a: 48 69 c0 e7 03 00 00    imul   $0x3e7,%rax,%rax
400691: 48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
400695: 48 ff 45 e8             incq   -0x18(%rbp)
400699: 48 81 7d e8 ff c9 9a    cmpq   $0x3b9ac9ff,-0x18(%rbp)
4006a0: 3b 
4006a1: 0f 9e c0                setle  %al
4006a4: 84 c0                   test   %al,%al
4006a6: 0f 85 53 ff ff ff       jne    4005ff <main+0x3b>
4006ac: 48 8d 45 c8             lea    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
4006b0: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
4006b3: e8 18 fe ff ff          callq  4004d0 <time@plt>
4006b8: 48 8b 45 c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
4006bc: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
4006be: 48 8b 45 d0             mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
4006c2: 89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
4006c4: 29 c1                   sub    %eax,%ecx
4006c6: 89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
4006c8: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
4006ca: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
4006ce: 48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
4006d1: bf cc 08 40 00          mov    $0x4008cc,%edi
4006d6: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
4006db: e8 c0 fd ff ff          callq  4004a0 <printf@plt>
4006e0: b8 00 00 80 7f          mov    $0x7f800000,%eax
4006e5: 89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)
4006e8: 48 8d 45 d0             lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
4006ec: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
4006ef: e8 dc fd ff ff          callq  4004d0 <time@plt>
4006f4: 48 c7 45 f8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
4006fb: 00 
4006fc: e9 90 00 00 00          jmpq   400791 <main+0x1cd>
400701: d9 45 f4                flds   -0xc(%rbp)
400704: d9 05 ea 01 00 00       flds   0x1ea(%rip)        # 4008f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
40070a: de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
40070c: d9 5d f4                fstps  -0xc(%rbp)
40070f: d9 45 f4                flds   -0xc(%rbp)
400712: d9 05 dc 01 00 00       flds   0x1dc(%rip)        # 4008f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
400718: de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
40071a: d9 5d f4                fstps  -0xc(%rbp)
40071d: d9 45 f4                flds   -0xc(%rbp)
400720: d9 05 ce 01 00 00       flds   0x1ce(%rip)        # 4008f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
400726: de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
400728: d9 5d f4                fstps  -0xc(%rbp)
40072b: d9 45 f4                flds   -0xc(%rbp)
40072e: d9 05 c0 01 00 00       flds   0x1c0(%rip)        # 4008f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
400734: de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
400736: d9 5d f4                fstps  -0xc(%rbp)
400739: d9 45 f4                flds   -0xc(%rbp)
40073c: d9 05 b2 01 00 00       flds   0x1b2(%rip)        # 4008f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
400742: de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
400744: d9 5d f4                fstps  -0xc(%rbp)
400747: d9 45 f4                flds   -0xc(%rbp)
40074a: d9 05 a4 01 00 00       flds   0x1a4(%rip)        # 4008f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
400750: de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
400752: d9 5d f4                fstps  -0xc(%rbp)
400755: d9 45 f4                flds   -0xc(%rbp)
400758: d9 05 96 01 00 00       flds   0x196(%rip)        # 4008f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
40075e: de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
400760: d9 5d f4                fstps  -0xc(%rbp)
400763: d9 45 f4                flds   -0xc(%rbp)
400766: d9 05 88 01 00 00       flds   0x188(%rip)        # 4008f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
40076c: de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
40076e: d9 5d f4                fstps  -0xc(%rbp)
400771: d9 45 f4                flds   -0xc(%rbp)
400774: d9 05 7a 01 00 00       flds   0x17a(%rip)        # 4008f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
40077a: de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
40077c: d9 5d f4                fstps  -0xc(%rbp)
40077f: d9 45 f4                flds   -0xc(%rbp)
400782: d9 05 6c 01 00 00       flds   0x16c(%rip)        # 4008f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x2c>
400788: de c9                   fmulp  %st,%st(1)
40078a: d9 5d f4                fstps  -0xc(%rbp)
40078d: 48 ff 45 f8             incq   -0x8(%rbp)
400791: 48 81 7d f8 ff c9 9a    cmpq   $0x3b9ac9ff,-0x8(%rbp)
400798: 3b 
400799: 0f 9e c0                setle  %al
40079c: 84 c0                   test   %al,%al
40079e: 0f 85 5d ff ff ff       jne    400701 <main+0x13d>
4007a4: 48 8d 45 c8             lea    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
4007a8: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
4007ab: e8 20 fd ff ff          callq  4004d0 <time@plt>
4007b0: 48 8b 45 c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
4007b4: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
4007b6: 48 8b 45 d0             mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
4007ba: 89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
4007bc: 29 c1                   sub    %eax,%ecx
4007be: 89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
4007c0: f3 0f 5a 45 f4          cvtss2sd -0xc(%rbp),%xmm0
4007c5: 89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
4007c7: bf e1 08 40 00          mov    $0x4008e1,%edi
4007cc: b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
4007d1: e8 ca fc ff ff          callq  4004a0 <printf@plt>
4007d6: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
4007db: c9                      leaveq 
4007dc: c3                      retq   
4007dd: 90                      nop
4007de: 90                      nop
4007df: 90                      nop
```

Comment: покажите получающийся ассемблер, а то так не понятно, что и как считается. кроме того, у вас результат умножения inf, а такое число может обрабатываться дольше.

Comment: Реквестирую кнопочку «свернуть\развернуть» для врезок. И если врезка больше 10 строк, то сворачивать по-умолчанию.

Comment: @kirelagin Принято к рассмотрению. Но очень большой листинг кода, редко когда желателен.

Comment: ну вот, в первом случае у вас пытается использовать mmx, но не очень эффективно. во втором - fmulp окружен большим количеством других команд.

Comment: Вторая версия работает намного медленнее. Не могу дать объяснения почему, но фатк.

Comment: так fpu выполняет операции над стеком регистров, из-за этого лишние задержки...

Answer (score 2):

После небольшого исследования оказалось что это возможно в GPU. В той же NVIDIA процессоры заточены на работу с float, но могу работать с int'ами, правда значительно медленнее. Насчет CPU пока есть гипотеза что в современных камнях эти операции выполняются за один такт.

Answer (score 1):

> Как оно впринципе может быть быстрее? засчет плохой реализации только :-D

fmul выполняется 3 такта (данные для pentium без mmx) и при этом fmul спариваются - можно запускать следующий fmul, не дожидаясь результата предыдущего. imul на том же процессоре выполняется 9 тактов (11 тактов для 8 и 16 битных чисел) и не спаривается.

для 32-битных чисел все вроде понятно - 32-битное умножение получает 64-битный результат именно за 9 тактов. в то же время для умножения с плавающей точкой нужно произвести только 23-битное умножение с 23-битным результатом (умножение старших битов) и сложение, которое можно выполнить параллельно.

Comment: Откуда взята цифра 9? Вот я смотрю на таблицу времён выполнения инструкций и вижу, что imul выполняется за 9 тактов в лучшем случае на Intel i386. 486й в лучшем случае справляется за 13. P5 - за десять тактов без возможности параллельной обработки на конвеерах, а P6 (pentium2) - за 1 микрооперацию (что не то же самое что такты). Смотрим fmul: 286: 110-125 тактов, 386: 25-37, 486: 11 тактов, P5: 3/1 FX, P6: 2 микрокоманды. Так о каких 9 тактах может идти речь на современных процессорах?

Comment: погуглил, нашел табличку с длительностью операций, в которой было указано, что на pentium без mmx imul выполняется минимум 9 тактов (11 тактов для 8 и 16 бит) при наличии значения в кеше.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно несколько вариантов ответа.

1. У float точность ниже. Числа float имеют меньшую точность, чем int: 23 бита против 31 бит. Это, соответственно, позволяет реализовать более короткие блоки математических операций над мантиссой. Производители GPU заметили пониженную точность float ещё на заре GPU-строения, и их внутренние блоки операций 23-24 битные. Пока в GPU не стали внедрять целочисленные блоки, операции с int эмулировались с использованием пары float (в чём можно было убедится, изучая дизассемблер).
2. half-float. Также на embedded GPU издревле имеются half-float (ну теперь такое есть на ARM, например), требующие всего 16 бит, что может быть таки быстрее, чем int.
3. Оптимизированный  float-формат. Если говорить не о float, а о некоторой арифметике с плавающей точкой - то можно хранить числа в диапазоне 0...1 (отметим, что именно в таком виде GPU работает с координатами, цветом etc.), то аппаратно их умножение не отличается от умножения int, только бит надо поменьше. Поэтому такой "float" будет быстрее int. Причём для операций сложения такого "float" действий больше (надо следить за нормированием в 0...1) - т.е. ответ вполне попадает под вопрос (с учётом возможности сравнимой с ADD аппаратной реализации MUL). Наверняка GPU активно используют такие "float" - ведь с точки зрения программиста ничего не меняется (например, в ранних OpenGL).

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае, вопрос, поставленный таким образом, неверен сам по себе. Если нет сопроцессора, который оперирует числами с плавающей точкой, то float умножение будет многократно медленнее, чем int умножение. Если же такой сопроцессор есть, то возможен вариант, когда время, затрачиваемое на передачу операндов в сопроцессор, вычисление результата операции и извлечение результата из сопроцессора, будет меньше, чем время, затрачиваемое на целочисленное умножение, если оно производится как серия операций сдвиг-сложение.

Comment: Такой случай на практике не встретишь в настоящее время. Дополню вопрос.

Comment: Все современные процы содержат сопроцессор в себе. Это было актуально до появления 80486 проца.

Comment: Вот как раз FPU - это он и есть.

Comment: Все современные процы содержат FPU -  это всего-лишь аббревеатура от Floating Point Unit.

Answer (score 0):

Есть предположение, что это справедливо для векторных процессоров.

Answer (score 0):

Ну как скаазть. В SSE там сплошные групповые вычисления для чсиел с плавающими точками. Ттак что то, что у вас нет сопроцессора не означает что вы не можете считать величины с плавающей точкой. Ещё как можете и очень быстро!!! Срауз 4 числа типа float одновременно. Если сравнить с целочисленными вычислениями на основном процессоре, то вполне это мб. медленнее. Прявяд я не вижу задая кроме графических где такое м.б. полезно. Если вы не занимаетесь графикой можете выкинуть все эти навороты.Там введены комманды, которые используются в матричных преобразованиях с матрицами 2х2. Ещё там используют такой тип как float16. Ну потому что разрешение экрана это небольшие чсила, но для выравивания изображения надо немножко округлять... Всё тоже делает графическая карта. NVIDIA к примеру. В научных расчётах всё вычичляется c плавающей точкой! Но наука умерла... А бугхалтерские расчёты требуют работы с целочисленными 16 байтными целыми. Я вот битый час пытаюсь можно ли в SSE как нибудь поделить 2 целх 128 битных чисел. Ответа пока нет... Там делятся только числа с плавающими точками. И пакетами. Мне такое не надо...